# Doctrine Mongo ODM reference 3 collections

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-odm, odm

Hi I'm trying to reference 3 collections but i fail fom 2 > 3 referencing, let me explain what i'm trying to do.

I have User class that have reference posts referenceMany > Posts and in posts i have referenceMany > comments.

**Note**: Doctrine Mongo ODM + Zend Framework 2

It's something like user write a post and someone comment on it.

```
/** @MongoDB\Document */
class Users {

    /** @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Posts", mappedBy="user") */
    private $posts;

}

/** @MongoDB\Document */
class Posts {

    /** @MongoDB\Id */
    private $wallPostId;

    /** @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Users", inversedBy="posts") */
    private $user;

    /** @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Comments", mappedBy="post") */
    private $comments;

    /** @MongoDB\String */
    private $content;

}

/** @MongoDB\Document */
class Comments {

    /** @MongoDB\Id */
    private $commentId;

    /** @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Posts", inversedBy="comments") */
    private $post;

    /** @MongoDB\String */
    private $content;

}
```

I'm trying this code to get all comments from any post

```
$post = $wallPostsAction->getWallPostById("5051d2a1e71a382c1b000000");
$output = "";
$output .= "Wall post content: " . $post->getContent() . "<br>";
//      $comment = new Comments();
//      $comment->setContent("Nice topic!");
//      $comment->setPost($post);
//      $this->dm->persist($comment);
//      $this->dm->flush();

echo count($post->getComments());
foreach($post->getComments() as $comment){
    $output .= " comment: " . $comment->getComment() . "<br>";
}
```

one of the document look like this for comment:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("---"),
   "post"?: {
     "$ref": "Posts",
     "$id": ObjectId("---"),
     "$db": "db" 
  },
   "content": "Nice topic!" 
}
```

Question is why i get 0 count for comment when i try to get them for specific post but when i try to get posts from user i can get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because all that getComments() returns is a cursor to that collection. Doctrine won't run any queries to obtain the information until you start to iterate over that collection.

Add this to the query in your getWallPostById method.

```
->field('comments')->prime(true)
```

This will tell doctrine to fetch the data about the comments when you fetch a post and then your cursor from getComments should have the count information you are looking for.

[Priming references](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/priming-references.html)

Comment: you are saying that i have to create custom query for this? what about 'echo count($post->getComments());' getter

Comment: It looks like you have a query inside getWallPostById already? inside a repository class perhaps? I'm saying if you add the prime selection to your query it will tell doctrine to get all the information about that reference on the first query, rather than waiting until you want to access that reference. That is why your 'echo count($post->getComments());' doesn't work first time, because without the prime operation it doesn't have any information about the comments. If you echoed that after your foreach statement I think you would get the answer you expected because you have used the reference

Comment: but this will load always comments with posts and that will not be lazy load right? intead get references will load all comments for all posts.

Comment: Correct. If you know you are going to be iterating over all the comments you should use prime so that you get all the info you need in two trips to the DB. Otherwise it's #comments+1 trips. If you still want the count of comments, before making a trip to the DB for a comment, you will have to store the count in the post document. This leads to more writes though as you'll have to update post for every comment.

Comment: I just reread the question. No it will only load all comments which references that post. If you know you are going to be using the getComments method after you find that post. You should use the prime option as this is the most optimal way to get the data back to your application.